# How to authenticate users in WinForms using asp.net simple membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, simplemembership

Am trying to find a way to use simple membership to authenticate users from a windows forms application (desktop version), all the users can register with web app for now (MVC 4).

It's is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [Client Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384339(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: what is the other way? I don't want to use service to do this.